# IUPAC Name of n-propyl benzene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, aromatic-compounds, hydrocarbons

What is the IUPAC name of *n*-propylbenzene? Is it propylbenzene or 1-phenylpropane, i.e. should the ring or the chain be considered the substituent?